# Samsung Smart TV SDK and TV version issue

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am wondering whether older version SDK (i.e. SDK 4.0) can be used to develop apps for 2014 TV, and whether SDK 5.1 can support 2011 TV???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes as long as with the older SDKs you don't use functionalities which are available only on the newer ones.